# AEM 6.3 - Inheritance in Sling Use classes

Tags: aem, sling

In AEM,  I have a Use class A which extends `WCMUsePojo`. It has one `activate()` method with `@Override` annotation where I read the property (lets say product) and assign to variable. Also, I have a getter method to read the property. Now, there is another class B which extends the Class A and has `activate()` method with `@Override` annotation. In activate method I am reading one more property.

Now, from HTL , I refer the Class B, and was trying to get "product property" (assuming that this property would be available in Class B via inheritance), But I am getting null value. But when I change the property modifier to `static` in Class A, then it works fine.

See the code below.

```
public class ClassA extends WCMUsePojo {  
    private String product;
 
    @Override   
    public void activate() throws Exception {    
        product = getProperties().get(“product”, "");
    }
  
    public String getProduct() {    
        return product;  
    }
}

public class ClassB extends ClassA {  
    private String lotno;
 
    @Override   
    public void activate() throws Exception {    
        lotno = getProperties().get(“lotno”, "");
    }
  
    public String getLotno() {    
        return lotno;  
    }
}


<div data-sly-use.productDetails="test.sample.ClassB"/>
${productDetails.product}
```

`${productDetails.product}` is `null` unless I change the product property to static in `ClassA`. Can somebody explain why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `super.activate()` in your activate-method of class B.

This is Standard-Java behavior. An overridden method replaces the inherited method. The  child-class has to call `super.method-xyz()` to re-use it. So the child class can control if the inherited method is called and when.

---

*Additional remarks:*

1. In case of an constructor you must call `super()`, because also the super-class must be initialized.
2. If you should use Sling-Models (what is mostly recommended), then you have the same effect. The annotation `@PostConstruct` is also only used for the child class. This is more confusing for everybody. That's why I don't recommend inheritance for Sling-Models in my projects. Often it is not needed.

Comment: thanks Alexander. But, how come it works when I declare the product variable and corresponding getter method as static in Class A

Comment: changing the modifier to `static` shouldn't change anything, I think the problem is that you use `test.sample.ClassA` in the HTL. if you use `test.sample.ClassB` in HTL you still will have empty product unless you execute `super.activate()` in `ClassB.activate()` method